Yocto meta-raspberrypi layer incompatible with scarthgap
I downloaded meta-raspberrypi layer and checked for the scarthgap branch (the LTS version).
meta-raspberrypi(folder)$git branch -r 
... 
origin/scarthgap 
...
meta-raspberrypi(folder)$git checkout -b scarthgap //set branch scarthgap

and followed the "Quick Start" instruction: https://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-raspberrypi/about/
Downloaded yocto poky and checked out the branch scarthgap and init the build environment with:
poky(folder)$ source oe-init-build-env ../rpi-build
../rpi-build$

If I now try to add the meta-raspberrypi layer it fails :
rpi-build$ bitbake-layers add-layer ~/workspace/yocto/meta-raspberrypi/
NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
ERROR: Layer raspberrypi is not compatible with the core layer which only supports these series: scarthgap (layer is compatible with walnascar styhead)
ERROR: Parse failure with the specified layer added, exiting.

I am new to Yocto, so the question is, am i doing something wrong? Or how to build a BSP for raspberry with yocto scarthgap?
UPDATE1: Tried to update the bblayers.conf manually but than it fails during "bitbake core-image-minimal" with :
Parsing of 958 .bb files complete (0 cached, 958 parsed). 1914 targets, 72 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
ERROR: No recipes in default available for:
  /home/daniel/workspace/yocto/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-graphics/mesa/mesa-gl.bbappend
  /home/daniel/workspace/yocto/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-graphics/mesa/mesa.bbappend


meta-rpi is well-maintained, I would assume that it's not compatible, if it says so. Can you double check that meta-rpi/conf/layer.conf contains LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_raspberrypi = "nanbield scarthgap"? The "not compatible" error normally stems from a layers.conf file, which does not declare compatibility with scarthgap

meta-rpi/conf/layer.conf only contains: LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_raspberrypi = "styhead walnascar". So does this mean that there is no support for the Yocto scarthgap (LTS) version?

I rather assume, scarthgap branch is not checked out for the repo, as the line is present upstream: https://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-raspberrypi/tree/conf/layer.conf?h=scarthgap#n12

When encountering the error Layer foo is not compatible with the core layer ..., first check the compatibility options for each layer. The option is normally located in meta-foo/conf/layer.conf and named LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_foo.
For this specific question, let's try to reproduce the behavior:
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-raspberrypi
cd meta-raspberrypi/
git checkout -b scarthgap
# fatal: A branch named 'scarthgap' already exists.
git checkout scarthgap
# Switched to branch 'scarthgap'

grep "LAYERSERIES_COMPAT" conf/layer.conf
# LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_raspberrypi = "nanbield scarthgap"

The variable tells the range of releases compatible. To find out if yours is included, use the releases page on the Yocto wiki.
For this question, meta-raspberrypi is compatible with scarthgap release. As I got an error on git checkout -b, I assume actual issue was checking out the branch in git. Due to the many git repositories involved, this is a common problem with Yocto projects. Yocto cooker is a tool to prevent git checkout issues. It has menu.json files to explicitly define which layer revision is checked out. They have an example menu.json for raspberry pi already.
Troubleshooting
If LAYERSERIES_COMPAT is not present in the current layer.conf file, I recommend to search the whole project. This is just to catch any non-standard file locations and doesn't take long with grep:
grep -r "LAYERSERIES" your/project/root

In rare cases the LAYERSERIES_COPMAT variable is set to the wrong releases. I only expect this for self-written or unpopular layers. Try to manually change the compatibility and fix any errors that occur.
